# Calculations: Antenna specs; SWR, Bandwidth, Rad.Eff, Q-factor

Tags: antenna, theory, bandwidth

Is it possible to give approx. answers about what an antenna is capable of? There is a lot of formuals out there, but every single one I found is based on actual measurement; input, output, SWR (Standing Wave Ratio) etc.

eg: I want to build a dipole for 450 MHz, what can I expect in bandwidth, q-factor, impedance matching, SWR ?

Is there some kind of standard chart board for diffrent antennas regarding the specs mentioned above? Like standard values you can expect if the construction is not that bad.

If you have a good website that can help me out please let me know. I want to learn how to do this for diffrent antennas.

Comment: At resonance, an antenna will look like a resistor with no reactive elements in its impedance therefore, what has q-factor got to do with this? Impedance matching is done external to the antenna. What is "SVR"?

Comment: Well the Q-factor has to do with the bandwidth.

Comment: OK I see what you mean now!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the link below - the best I've found on dipole antennas:

http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/rd/pubs/whp/whp-pdf-files/WHP132.pdf